# Replace a character with another character via indices from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of indices of a positions where I wish to replace a character in a text file with the character '+'. So my text file has 250 thousand characters and I want to replace only the ones at these indexes.

```
a = [105, 777, 1449, 2121, 2793, 3465, 4137, 4809, 5481, 6153, 6825,
     7497, 8169, 8841, 9513, 10185, 10857, 11529, 12201, 12873, 13545, 14217,]
```

My first thought was to run a for loop over the list:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(a):
     Raw_text[i] = Raw_text[i].replace(']','+')
```

but this gives me the output:

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

Which I understand that error after looking at some stackoverflow questions, but how do I replace only those items in a list like that or even larger than that list?

Comment: It looks like you only want to replace the character if it's an `]`. Is that correct? How did you get the indexes? Are you trying to replace _all_ the `]` characters in the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always convert your string into a list, and then re-convert it back later.

```
raw_list = list(raw_text)
for i in a:
    raw_list[i] = '+'

raw_text = ''.join(raw_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to replace them at a particular index

```
   text_file = "0123456789"

   indexes = [1,3,6,9]

   for index in indexes:
       text_file = text_file[:index] + '+' + text_file[index+1:]
```

**text_file result:** items at index 1, 3, 6, and 9 replaced with '+'

```
"0+2+45+78+"
```